# Checking if strings in a file match a regex and then print out the first string in that row if it doesn't match

Tags: grep, macos

To start off, I'm new so I'm still learning..

The data set file is sort of like this

```
101 80 10 27598 General Tao Vancouver 01:45:10 01:46:10 00:43:00 00:59:59 01:25:10
```

I'm trying to check the times to make sure they match the format of `/d/d:/d/d:/d/d`, and if it doesn't match that regex, then it prints out the first number (101 in this case) of that row

I've been trying one liners in CLI but to no avail.

```
grep '/d/d:/d/d:/d/d' file.txt
```

nothing happens even for this

edit1:
In the dataset, there are data that look like 01:4510 or some such

and the example output I wish to get is:

```
104 80 10 27598 BigBelly Vancouver 01:4510 01:46:10 00:43:00 00:59:59 01:25:10
```

Comment: Have tried:
grep -v '/d/d/:/d/d/:/d/d' file.txt
Which worked on a list that i created to test this out but it did not work on the list that had 5500 lines

Comment: If you post sample input that only `sort of` looks like your real data then you stand a good chance of getting a solution that only `sort of` works for your real data.

Answer (score 5):

You must have been thinking of the `\d` regexp operator of `perl` to match on decimal digits. But note that few `grep` implementations support it. The standard equivalent is `[[:digit:]]`.

Some `grep` implementations support `\d` if passed a `-P` option (to use perl-like regexps instead of basic regexps).

So with those, you could do:

```
grep -Pv '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d' < file.txt
```

To return the lines that don't contain a string that matches that pattern.

(note that they are *backslashes* not *forward slashes*)

Or:

```
grep -Pv '(\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d){5}\s*$' < file.txt
```

for the lines that don't end in 5 such timestamps.

To return the first field in that case, you could do instead (with `grep` implementations that also support `-o`)

```
grep -Po '^(?!.*(\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d){5}\s*$)\s*\K\S+' < file.txt
```

This time using the negative-look-ahead perl regexp operator instead of using `grep`'s `-v`.

The `grep` of macOS (which you say you're using, I've now removed the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag from your question and replaced it with [macos](/questions/tagged/macos)) happens to be one of those few whose basic regexps support `\d`, but it doesn't support `-P`, so those `(?!...)` and `\K` operators are not available there.

A standard (and more legible) equivalent would be:

```
awk '!/([[:digit:]]{2}:){2}[[:digit:]]{2}/ {print $1}' < file.txt
```

`awk` uses *extended regexps* which is yet another dialect. Beware some implementations, including `mawk` still don't support the `{2}` interval operator nor character classes.

In `mawk`, you'd do:

```
awk '!/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/ {print $1}' < file.txt
```

That should also work with other `awk` implementations, but beware that for some `[0-9]` could match on characters other than 0123456789 (non-ASCII ones, so would probably not be an issue with your input).

Or again, to check all 5 last fields match the pattern:

```
awk '
  {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      if (!($(NF-i) ~ /^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$/)) {
        print $1
        next
      }
  }' < file.txt
```

Comment: im using:
cat file.txt | grep -v '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'
but it just prints out the first line which is the names of each columns and then it stops after that, even though i know for sure theres time data there that doesnt match the regex

Comment: @Wickerman, I assume you meant `-Pv` instead of `-v` above. The regexp matches on lines that contains at least one occurrence of HH:MM:SS. Please edit your question to show at least one example of a line that it *should* report.

Comment: For some reason -Pv doesn't work, only -v

Comment: I have edited the question as requested for clarity

Comment: @Wickerman, that line you've added does contain some valid HH:MM:SS, so it would not be reported. If we are to check that *all* timestamps are valid, then we need to know where those timestamp are expected to be found. For instance, in your first sample the 7th field contains `Vancouver` which is not a valid timestamp. Are timestamps always the 5 last fields of every line? What operating system are you on?

Comment: I am on Mac OS, which I now realize I'm in the unix stackexchange and I should be thrown out for blasphemy. However I've found a semi solution:

cat file.txt | awk '{ print $7 }' | grep -v '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'

This outputs location names but surprisingly also irregular HH:MM:SS, then i search manually in the textfile looking for the irregular HHMMSS and manually copy down the first field. The last 5 fields is supposed to contain the HH:MM:SS format, but it seems to have a lot of overlap from other columns. So i'll just print $5 to $11 looking for it.

Comment: @Wickerman, macOS is on topic here as long as it's about unixy questions about it. But it didn't help that you tagged your question  with *Linux*!

Comment: @EdMorton, ast-open's `grep` supports `-P` as well (though does not use PCRE), and all of its BRE, ERE, ARE, PRE recognise `\d`. The OP is actually on macOS, I can't tell whether macOS `grep` support `\d` or not.

Comment: Well, TIL that grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD on MacOS apparently does support `\d` (just tried it). I swear there all almost no tools that are just POSIX-compliant installed on any system any more...

Comment: The OPs [last comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600304/checking-if-strings-in-a-file-match-a-regex-and-then-print-out-the-first-string/600308?noredirect=1#comment1120838_600308) makes me think there's more to their real input than they've shared with us so far and that it doesn't actually look very much like the example provided in their question.

Comment: @EdMorton, supporting `\d` does not make a `grep` implementation *not* POSIX compliant as POSIX leaves the behaviour unspecified if you use `\d` in a BRE or ERE. It does say however that `[\d]` is required to match on either backslash or `d`, so I'd expect macOS (which has been certified as compliant) does as well (though I cannot test).

Comment: I know, I just left a similar comment on a different post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102809/posix-abcdef-to-ab-bc-cd-de-ef#comment111588650_63102809). `grep '[\d]'` on MacOS does match `d` and ```\``` and does not match `8`.